# IF function runs, not ELSE

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Can someone tell me why the `else` of this function doesn't run, but `if` does? Also is there something that is making the code run slowly? Below is my code.

```
function SignUserIn() {
// Get elements
const Email = document.getElementById("txtEmail");
const Password = document.getElementById("txtPassword");

// Get email and pass
const email = Email.value;
const password = Password.value;
const auth = firebase.auth();

//Sign In
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password' || errorCode === 'auth/invalid-email' || errorCode === 'auth/user-disabled' || errorCode === 'auth/user-not-found') {
            window.alert(errorMessage);
            document.getElementById("txtPassword").value = "";
        }
        else {
            //Realtime listener
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(frebaseUser => {
                sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);
                window.alert("You Are Successfully Signed In! Welcome " + email);
                window.location = "homepage.html";
            });
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: May be the else condition is never satisfied.

Comment: What does `console.log(errorCode)` show?

Comment: @Barmar if the login information is incorrect (i.e email or password don't match) then it will display one of the correct error messages (auth.wrong-password, auth/invalid-email etc.) the ones that are listed in the if condition.  if its correct then nothing.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee if the else condition is never satisfied then the if statement should be satisfied no? As far is i know if the if condition is not met then it will conduct the else condition. (apologies if that was confusing)

Comment: The `.catch()` function only runs when the promise reports an error. If the login is successful, why would it report an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.catch()` method only runs when the promise is rejected. If you want to run code when the promise resolves or is rejected, you should use `.then()`. It takes two function arguments, one for success, the other for reject.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function() {
        // Handle success here
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(frebaseUser => {
            sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);
            window.alert("You Are Successfully Signed In! Welcome " + email);
            window.location = "homepage.html";
        });
    }, function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        window.alert(errorMessage);
        document.getElementById("txtPassword").value = "";
    });
```